# Drought Prediction

Tags: weather-forecasting, precipitation, drought

I have read many articles about drought forecasting, but I always come across the concept of 'lead time' for SPI forecasting. Please can someone who knows the subject briefly explain the concept of 'lead time' to me? As far as I understand, it is a time scale, but how is it different from a timescale?

Comment: In most meteorology I'd picture lead time to be how far ahead of time you can predict it before it happens and timescale to be the length of the event (the drought in this case) or perhaps the product issued (if it's like a forecast for one month at a time).  I can't speak with certainty because I'm not familiar with SPI, and haven't followed drought forecasting that much overall, but that's my guess